# Why did my boolean test switch in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, boolean-logic

I have this bash function that checks if I'm on the internet. It helps with moments where I need a quick `if internet-connected` test in a bash script.

With that being so useful for the last month, I tried to replicate its design to have a simple ubuntu tester that tests whether or not the OS is Ubuntu. Then this happened...

#### test.sh

```
internet-connected(){
    wget -q --spider http://google.com
    if [ $? -eq 1 ]
    then
        echo 'internet is connected'
        return 1
    else
        echo 'internet is not connected'
        return 0
    fi
}

echo "testing internet-connected"

if internet-connected
then
    echo 'connected'
else
    echo 'not connected'
fi

check-for-ubuntu(){
    tester=$(lsb_release -i | grep -e "Ubuntu" -c)
    if [ $tester -eq 1 ]
    then
        echo 'ubuntu detected'
        return 1
    else
        echo 'ubuntu not detected'
        return 0
    fi
}

echo ""
echo "testing check-for-ubuntu"

if check-for-ubuntu
then
    echo 'this is ubuntu'
else
    echo 'this is not ubuntu'
fi
```

#### Output

```
testing internet-connected
internet is not connected
connected

testing check-for-ubuntu
ubuntu detected
this is not ubuntu
[Finished in 0.9s]
```

#### My Question

Why does the logic seem backwards in these two functions?

> You guys answered this really well, thank you.

Comment: Good question, it looks simple enough to me. The standard first step in debugging a shell script is to put `set -x` at the beginning, so you see all the commands as they're executed.

Comment: Wait - both **are** the same - in **both** cases the message from inside the function is the opposite of the message from outside the function.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with @Barmar on quality of the question -- there's a lot of code unrelated to the issue at hand included, thus violating the "M" ("minimal") part of [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I meant it was an interesting question. And I thought having two test cases to compare makes the example better -- one example would have been *too* M.

Comment: @Barmar, ...sure, but there's no need for external code involved. You could get rid of the `wget` calls or the `lsb_release | ...` and just replace them with constant `true` or `false` invocations that anyone could run on any POSIX machine.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy He thought the two cases were acting differently, and the only significant difference was what external commands he was running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shell script is not C (or C++/Java/etc./etc./etc.).

- 0 means success (true).
- Anything else means error (false).

Your return values are backwards.

Comment: For exit status purposes, that's true even in C -- it's what the (0) `EXIT_SUCCESS` and (1) `EXIT_FAILURE` constants are for. See [the relevant glibc docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html).

Comment: True, but that's because C programs' exit codes are read by shell scripts.

Comment: I disagree that this is a shell-driven convention -- it's a *logic*-driven convention -- if you had it any other way, you couldn't have more than one error code, and thus you couldn't distinguish between different kinds of errors via exit status. The UNIX convention of using a single-byte exit code would thus be far less useful in general.

Comment: Yes, Unix exit codes are "status", not "boolean", and therefore the natural form for shell scripts. Zero does not mean "success" so much as "no error".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Why does that "logic" not apply to programming languages like C? Why do they have lots of true values, but only one false value? Thus necessitating a separate `errno` variable.

Comment: @Barmar, well-written C code has a *lot* of places where `errno` or return values following similar conventions need to be explicitly checked (with 0 meaning no-error and a nonzero value meaning that an error occurred). Doing that the conventional way means either putting in an explicit not, or storing the return value and operating on it separately -- boilerplate, in short. C, however, is designed to not do things behind one's back -- explicitness over terseness is very much part of being a "portable assembler" -- so boilerplate is acceptable there.

Comment: @Barmar, ...the level of explicitness required to write good C, on the other hand, would be awful for a shell language intended to be tersely gluing components together. Can you imagine trying to invert the exit status of every member of a pipeline to make `pipefail` behave as intended?

Comment: @Barmar, ...anyhow, what I was describing as a "logic-driven convention" was having the 0 exit status indicate success, as opposed to having the shell treat success as truth. The extent to which the latter follows from the former... well, I'd hope it'd be obvious on its face, given shell's design intent.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Well, "success" and "true" seem to be conflated, since we use `if` to test them both in their respective languages. Not to mention `if /bin/true` in shell.

Comment: Indeed -- but for a language intended to be gluing together components that follow UNIX's exit status conventions (conventions that exist for reasons that stand on their own even without the shell's existence), there's good cause for that conflation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy My simple point was that the logic of whether to equate 0 or non-zero with success/true is dictated by the way the languages are used, it's not more general.

Comment: ...and my point is that whether to equate 0 with **success** (lack of any error) is in fact more general (to C and UNIX conventions, at least), even if whether to equate it with **truth** is specific to an individual language's design goals. Witness again `errno` &c. So I concede exactly half the point.

Answer (score 1):

Your `check-for-ubuntu` can be just this using `grep -q`:

```
check-for-ubuntu() {
    lsb_release -i | grep -q "Ubuntu"
}
```

`grep -q` will return 1 or 0 based on pattern `Ubuntu` in `lsb_release` command.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question though.

Comment: This doesn't explain why his original function doesn't work. It looks pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: Yes it looks simple to me also. This is just an improvement to avoid multiple commands to do the same.